# RTMP Delphi Client library

Tags: delphi, rtmp

I tried to make the connection with indy tcp but this didnt work, So
I was looking for a RTMP library in Delphi to generate request to a rtmp:// server. Anyone knows a free/open source library that allow me to do this?

**Thanks, BBLN.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a Delphi library, but rtmpdump from MPlayer provides a DLL (librtmp).

You could write a Delphi unit to access it. Depending on what your exact goal is you could also just use the rtmpdump tool to download the video file.

http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/